# Receiving DUP! when doing ping to Redhat VirtIO interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, ping

Wasn't able to find anything related so here goes! :D

Inside Redhat terminal, whenever I do a ping towards a `Redhat virtIO Ethernet Adapter` interface of Windows it results to DUP! responses.
I've tried pinging either one of those two virtIO interfaces and both yields to duplicate ping responses...

I've read somewhere that it *may* be due to [Windows' RRAS](http://codeblog.co.uk/vmware-duplicate-ping-responses/)

Though I'm afraid that turning this off would disable also my capability to Remote access via RDP to this Windows machine.

So does anybody encountered this?

Windows interface setup:

```
Windows IP Configuration

  Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : G162401EN
  Primary Dns Suffix . . . . . . . . . . .  : 
  Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
  IP Routing Enabled . . . . . . . . . . .  : No
  WINS Proxy Enabled . . . . . . . . . . .  : No

Ethernet Adapter EXT-CP2-EL5:

  Connection-specific DNS Suffix . . . . .  :
  Description . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Red Hat VirtIO Ethernet Adapter #5
  Physical Address . . . . . . . . . . . .  : F0:X:Y:Z:A:B
  DHCP Enabled . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  : No
  Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . . . . . : Yes
  IPv4 Address . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  : 10.40.90.163(Preferred)
  Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.224
  Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . . . . . :
  NetBIOS over Tcpip . . . . . . . . . . .  : Enabled

Ethernet Adapter EXT-CP1-EL4: 

  Connection-specific DNS Suffix . . . . .  :
  Description . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Red Hat VirtIO Ethernet Adapter #4
  Physical Address . . . . . . . . . . . .  : F0:D:E:F:G:H
  DHCP Enabled . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  : No
  Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . . . . . : Yes
  IPv4 Address . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  : 10.40.90.131(Preferred)
  Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.224
  Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . . . . . :
  NetBIOS over Tcpip . . . . . . . . . . .  : Enabled
```